# Non-GPL library that can connect to a MySQL database?

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, objective-c, c

I'm looking for a C, C++, or Objective-C library that can connect to a MySQL database. I'm aware of libmysqlclient (GPL) and SQLAPI++ (non-GPL).

Are there any alternatives besides SQLAPI++ that can be included in a non-GPL project?

Comment: Is LGPL okay? I'm assuming you just don't want the GPL to infect your code.

Comment: I just wrote this https://github.com/ciaranj/MySqueakQl for anyone else who comes this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iODBC](http://iodbc.org/) is BSD-licensed, and provides an ODBC client implementation.

The user could then install the [MySQL Connector/ODBC](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) to interface with the MySQL server.

Answer (score 4):

The MySQL C connector used to be LGPL (thus, allowing dynamic linking to proprietary code). Oracle has changed the license from LGPL to GPL starting from versions later than 3.23.58.

To use a LGPL connector therefore you have the following options:

- Use the old version (i.e. LGPL) of the MySQL connector: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/lgpl-mysql-client-library-32358/
- Use the MariaDB connector (a fork of the old LGPL MySQL connector): https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-connector-c/
- Use Qt's database drivers (which are LGPL and have connectors for databases): http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html
- Use Libdrizzle: https://launchpad.net/libdrizzle

Answer (score 1):

Try [SOCI](http://soci.sourceforge.net/) or [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/). Both are under the [Boost Software License](http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt).

EDIT: Indeed you are right. And it seems you're in a hot spot and would have to buy a MySQL license, at least according to the following

[GPL and libmysqlclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038881/gpl-and-libmysqlclient)

[About MySQL++, GPL and LGPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260591/about-mysql-gpl-and-lgpl)

[MySQL licensing and GPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620696/mysql-licensing-and-gpl)

Comment: True, but both require libmysqlclient.