# Using GNU LGPLv3 platform on back-end of a commercially-hosted solution

Tags: licensing, hosted-app

My company is wanting to productionize a suite of drawing (CAD) and mapping solutions (GIS) as a commercial solution in a hosted environment (users would access via the web on a subscription basis).  On the back-end, we wish to implement a content/document management platform that is available under GNU LGPLv3.  It is our intent to *not* distribute the LGPL application nor will we expose its user interface to end-users (it will be used akin to a database for our solutions).  That said, does this usage comply with the license given that we will charge customers for our solution?  Also, as we are *not* modifying the LGPL platform's source code (we are accessing it programmatically only via its published web services API), are we required to make available our source code?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing GPL or LGPL services via an API doesn't require you to make the source code of your application available, as long as you don't give the code to your customers.  See the related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620696/mysql-licensing-and-gpl) about MySQL.

If the platform was [AGPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affero_General_Public_License), I believe that would be a different story, as accessing an AGPL service via a network is considered as equivalent to distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The LGPL does not prohibit commercial use. And as long as you're not distributing the software, I don't see why this should be even a question. Anyway you're merely asking for a compliance check but that can only be done by your companies lawyers, if it's an issue for them. So ask a lawyer instead, and that lawyer will ask you about the specifics of your software and then checks if it's compliant or not.

Comment: Did you mean doesn't prohibit?